# My app crashes when I try to implement a Scroll Bar

Tags: android, crash, android-emulator

I have a problem with my app, i started coding in Android studio recently and i got a problem i can`t solve. 
So i have a main page with 4 activities, when i run the program in the emulator the app opens and 3 of the activities work perfectly but the one where i try to implement the scrollbar crashes when i click to open the activity.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" 
    tools:context=".coffeeGrowth" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:keepScreenOn="true"
                    android:text="@string/large_text"
                    android:textColor="#008000"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

And the crash:

> 07/03 16:54:21: Launching app $ adb install-multiple -r -t -p
>   com.example.android.coffeeknowledge C:\Users\Daud
>   Jawad\CoffeeKnowledge\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>   Split APKs installed $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.example.android.coffeeknowledge/com.example.android.coffeeknowledge.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Connected to
>   process 10196 on device emulator-5554 Capturing and displaying logcat
>   messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the
>   "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page. D/:
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8aa1c1c0, tid
>   10196 D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established
>   0x8aa1c540, tid 10218 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose
>   config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext:
>   0x8a9fe920: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0x8a9fe920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99d98910) W/art: Before Android 4.1,
>   method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0x8a9fe920: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99d98910) D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM E/AndroidRuntime: ***FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.android.coffeeknowledge, PID: 10196
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.coffeeknowledge/com.example.android.coffeeknowledge.coffeeGrowth}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.android.coffeeknowledge.coffeeGrowth.onCreate(coffeeGrowth.java:98)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)*** 
>   Application terminated.

Thank you,
Daud.

Comment: the scrollview must has only one child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is wrong my friend.

A ScrollView is not a layout option. Its a view. So you need to wrap your Layout around the scrollview. Keep in mind, a ScrollView can only have ONE child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" tools:context=".coffeeGrowth" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/large_text"
        android:textColor="#008000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I understand now, i found some tutorials that didn`t explain that good enough.  I tried the code and it still crashes the same way.

Comment: Are you showing the right code? You said ScrollBar. You must be not showing something else. Can you paste the logcat error

Comment: I added the error and in the Log this appears                                                      
                                                                                                                             
   4:10 PM Emulator: [11604]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/async/AsyncSocketServer.cpp:99:Error when accepting host connectionError message: Unknown error

4:11 PM Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x502 internal 0x1906 format 0x1906 type 0x1401

Comment: you have a NPE on an onclicklistener. show your code. you are setting an onclicklistener to a view that doesnt exist.

Comment: The setting was ok, i don`t know why that happened, maybe because when i chose the activity i chose fullscreen activity and then completley changed the XML. I solved the problem though, i deleted the activity and created a new one and just pasted the code. Thank you!

Comment: But i want to add a horizontal scrollBar to another activity. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If it is solved, please up vote and accept answer. :) There is a view called Horizontal Scroll View. you can use that.